# flex mobile project : send emails

Tags: email, mobile, flex4.5

I want to send email that contains form as a body from my mobile app. I am searching in internet , but I am able to find help only for desktop or web applications. I came to know that I can use "mailto" protocol,but I dont know how can I use it for mobile project.
Please help me with some examples or tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works the same as it does inside a regular flex application. In your send method add something like this:

var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("mailto:youremailhere@yourdomain.com");
navigateToURL(urlRequest);

I did notice that the mailto is case sensitive (mailTo worked in the emulator but not on the device, so make sure that it is "mailto"